# Jenkins Pipeline Script to invoke ansible playbook

Tags: jenkins, ansible, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline

I am trying to invoke the Ansible playbook from the Jenkins pipeline script.
For this I tried below:

```
def invokeAnsiblePlaybook() {
    echo ("Start invokeAnsiblePlaybook")

    ansiblePlaybook becomeUser: 'user01', credentialsId: 'user01_ssh_pwd', installation: 'ansible 2.9.0', inventory: '/home/user01/repo/MISC/playbooks/inventory_v1.ini', limit: '198.168.11.22', playbook: '/home/user01/repo/MISC/playbooks/Query.yml', sudo: true, sudoUser: 'user01', tags: 'CheckTime'

    echo ("End invokeAnsiblePlaybook")
}
```

I have configured ssh Username/Password of the Ansible remote Linux server into Jenkins.
In the above code '198.168.11.22' is the remote Linux server IP where Ansible is installed.
When I was running the job it gives me the below error.

```
[JobName] $ sshpass ******** ansible-playbook /home/user01/repo/MISC/playbooks/IAM-Query.yml -i /home/user01/repo/MISC/playbooks/inventory_v1.ini -l 198.168.11.22 -t CheckTime -s -U user01 -u user01 -k
ERROR! the playbook: /home/user01/repo/MISC/playbooks/IAM-Query.yml could not be found
FATAL: command execution failed
hudson.AbortException: Ansible playbook execution failed
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.ansible.AnsiblePlaybookBuilder.perform(AnsiblePlaybookBuilder.java:262)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.ansible.workflow.AnsiblePlaybookStep$AnsiblePlaybookExecution.run(AnsiblePlaybookStep.java:400)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.ansible.workflow.AnsiblePlaybookStep$AnsiblePlaybookExecution.run(AnsiblePlaybookStep.java:321)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution$1$1.call(AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
    at hudson.security.ACL.impersonate(ACL.java:367)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution$1.run(AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:44)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I am using Jenkins 2.249.1 and Ansible 2.9.0.

Comment: What is not clear to you in _ERROR! the playbook: /home/user01/repo/MISC/playbooks/IAM-Query.yml could not be found_? Your playbook is not there, either you misplaced it on your server or your VCS does not pull it where you expect it to be.

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε We have different servers for Jenkins and Ansible, playbook is placed in Ansible server and the IP is 198.168.11.22.

Comment: So you have a misunderstanding on how Ansible works. In Ansible there is a controller, which should have the playbook since it is running it. Passing a limit to it means that you are limiting the hosts it is going to run the result of this playbook on, not where the playbook actually stands.

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε please correct me if I am wrong, I have to place the playbook inside the Jenkins Server

Comment: Indeed, and the best idea, to me, would be that it goes in the same SVC as your Jenkinsfile, so you can make your pipeline invoke it locally in the Jenkins workspace.

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε How can I pass "--extra-vars 'host_group=testlab_demo01'" into Jenkins pipeline job when I am invoking a playbook

Comment: @user3441151 Documentation for that can be found at https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/ansible/. Besides that, I would recommend following β.εηοιτ.βε advice.

Answer (score 1):

You can install ansible plugin in Jenkins and could try using below sample code. I have used this code for my EBS R12.2 cloning. Which helps me to refresh EBS instance from source to target with one single click in Jenkins.
Note: - This code supports snippet is used for scripted pipeline.

stage("EBS R12.2 - EBS Cloning") {
echo "Executing the ebs cloning script here."
ws("/DATA MIGR/ebs/scripts") {
ansiColor('xterm') {
ansiblePlaybook(
credentialsId: "",
playbook: "/.yml",
inventory: "/.yml",
extras: " -e '<ANS_VARIABLE>=<JENKINS_VAR>'",
startAtTask: "ACTION",
colorized: true,
hostKeyChecking: false
)
}
}
}

Where,
CRED: - Cred id(ex. ssh credentials) in jenkins from which you wat to execute playbook.
ANS_VARIABLE: - Variable name defined in ansible playbook.
JENKINS_VAR: - Variable name defined in jenkins.
ACTION: - Task name from where you want to start playbook execution.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).